# Zenity doesn't cancel or display the message, because it doesn't see the variable

Tags: bash, variables, wget, zenity

I wrote a simple script to wget and zenity to cancellation:

```
#!/bin/bash
((
   wget http://d3qnbzt7ix5jlv.cloudfront.net/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso & export PID=$$
   wait $PID
   export YES=$?
)&) | zenity --progress --pulsate --auto-close
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  kill $PID
fi
if [ "$YES" = "0" ]; then
   zenity --info
elif [ "$YES" = "1" ]; then
   zenity --error
fi
```

Kill not see the process $PID. Zenity doesn't display the final window ($YES). Why?

Comment: you have two subshells being created i.e. '(' first sub-shell, '('  second subshell as the first 2 chars in your script. No child process can change the value or create a variable in a parent process. This is true for shells too. You can pass back a value for assignment in the parent, i.e. YES=$( wget ... ), but because you want to pipe into zenity, that won't work. There may be a way to duplicate output or reassign stdin for each process using `exec 4>&1` sort of notation, but I don't have the time to figure it out. Also the meaning of the end your first sentence is not clear. Good luck.

Comment: I want the shell to read from the subshell $! and $?.

Comment: set up some simple tests, ignoring the pipe to zenity and you'll see that you can't change values of variables between subshells, you can only 'send back' the value via cmd-substitution, i.e. `var=$( printf "value\n")` Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly an answer but a comment would garble the code snippet:

---

`/usr/bin/userinstall-wget`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# a wget wrapper to get these under a separate shell *and* progname

[ -n "$1" -a -n "$2" ] || exit 1

LANG=C \
wget -O "$1" --content-disposition --progress=bar:force:noscroll "$2" 2>&1 \
| stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tr '>' '\n' \
| stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 sed -rn 's/^.*\<([0-9]+)%\[.*$/\1/p'
```

---

```
# NB: those coughing at this particular killall are welcome with patches
download() {
        userinstall-wget "$outfile" "$url" | (
                trap 'killall userinstall-wget' HUP
                zenity --progress --time-remaining --auto-close --auto-kill \
                        --text="Wait please..." \
                        --title="Downloading file"
        )
}
```

---

These have been thrown together as a part of userinstall wrapper scripts for ALT Linux.

HTH

PS: drop `--progress=bar:force:noscroll` with older wget